# <div> element inside <ul> element, hierarchy is changed in IE, ASP.NET Repeater control

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, repeater, html-lists

I have the following Repeater control to display a list of elements.

```
 <td id="tdLeftBlock">
            <ul id="leftList"> 
              <asp:Repeater ID="rptLatestListingsLeft" runat="server"               
                     OnItemDataBound="rptLatestListingsLeft_OnItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <div id="divMapPinLeft" runat="server">
                   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMapPinIndexLeft"></asp:Label>
                 </div>
                 <li id='<%# String.Format("liBusiness{0}", Eval("BusinessID")) %>' 
                                                     style="padding-bottom: 30px">
                      <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkBusiness" runat="server">
                                        <%# Eval("BusinessName")%>
                                    </asp:HyperLink>
                    <div class="divAddressLeft"><%# Eval("City")%>, <%# 
                                                   Eval("ProvinceCode")%></div>
                    <div id="divStatusLeft"><%# GetStatus(Eval("BusinessID"))%> | 
                  <span class="statusTag"><%# GetDay(Eval("UpdateDate"))%></span></div>
                 </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>                    
            </ul> 
         </td>
```

Firefox and other non IE browsers understand that the div #divMapPinLeft must be rendered at the same level as its li sibling. IE, on the other hand, doesn't recognize this hierarchy and puts the div under the li  in each Repeater item. Solutions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to use invalid HTML? A `div` cannot be a child of `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in such way. `li` is only allowed tag under `ul`, you have invalid html. You can't put `div` there. Put your `div` under `li`.